# What difference between Context Map and Bounded Context in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, subdomain, bounded-contexts

Im new to learn DDD concept and i cant understand something.

1-What difference between Context Map and Bounded Context and SubDomain?

2-How to recognize relation between Bounded Context ?

Comment: I think the answer for this could be a few chapters of a book. Just a suggestion to read a bit more about DDD. You could start here: https://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping/ . [Los Techies](https://lostechies.com/) also has a lot of good articles about DDD.

Answer (score 5):

As @Augusto mentioned, this is a couple of chapters in the *blue book*, but here goes.

The **domain model** is found in the business rules and how people talk but a simplification of it is captured in code. Certain naming is consistent and the necessary invariants are enforced in the model.

A **bounded context** is mostly conceptual (might be a namespace, module, project in code as well...). It is the *intention* to keep a domain model consistent within it. So within the context, a certain ubiquitous language is used. And a model need only serve the needs of THAT context. It is the boundary in which the model can be used. In terms of recognizing these relationships? Some might be subtle but most are not. At least some people in the team will want to "avoid duplication" by unifying the model... so that is a clear indication that there is a relationship. Names are often the same or similar... or could be the same but one is better suited to one domain and another to another domain.

A **context map** is a bit more of a project management tool. It is a map of how different contexts (and the models within) relate to each other. In an *Ordering Domain* in an e-commerce system you may have a product. It would lead to A LOT of complication trying to have a unified Product in a model that spanned *Ordering*, *Payments*,  *Content* for the website and *Inventory* domains (for example). So each of those domains should have a separate model. The context map is a diagram and related documentation that relates these bounded contexts together since there would be relationships and translation of data across from one model to the next, as an order flows through the system.

The last element you asked about is a **subdomain**. Here you probably are referring to a **generic subdomain**. Personally, I think the name is a little confusing. It makes it seem like a subset of the model. Maybe this is on purpose but I generally think of them as their own domain, just one that is not central to the business's proposition. For instance, if the aforementioned e-commerce company was known for its same day or next day delivery, then they probably shouldn't buy an off-the-shelf solution to inventory and shipping management. On the other hand, if they were focusing on a market that just wanted the cheapest deal but didn't mind waiting a few days, then that would be a perfect candidate for a generic subdomain.

[My DDD glossary](https://devonburriss.me/ddd-glossary/) which has plenty of links at the bottom to more detailed articles.

If you are serious about learning this subject and can get your hands on some books:

- Domain-driven Design by Eric Evans
- Implementing Domain-driven Design by Vaughn Vernon
- Domain-driven Design made functional by Scott Wlaschin (my favourite)

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to mark it as the answer if it answered your question. Thanks!

Comment: BC might be a module?

Comment: @AlirezaRahmanikhalili it might be. It might be its own microservice. Some languages (C# for example) do not even have a concept of a module. It is more about a set of problems is being solved in a context and so the language is shared. eg. A product is the same `Product` everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

As said in the comment, this is a wide subject, and very important in DDD. It is the strategic part of DDD. Anyway I will try to answer your questions with an overall explanation:

---

DDD is about understanding and distilling the domain of the problem we want to solve. It is a continuous process of learning about the domain, talking to the domain experts. All people (developers, business people, etc) speak the same language. This language is used everywhere (conversations, documentation, source code, ...). It is called the Ubiquitous Language (UL).

The problem domain may have different areas of functionality, which would be domains too. They are the **subdomains**. So a subdomain is a subset of the problem domain. It is like splitting the problem into smaller subproblems, and a subdomain would be the domain of a subproblem. There are 3 kinds of subdomains:

- **Core**: The point of distillation is to discover the subdomain that has value for the business, i.e., the one that will make your product better than others of the same kind. Such subdomain is the "core subdomain". For example, in "project management", the "task assignement" would be core.
- **Supporting**: It is specialized in some business aspect that helps the core functionality. For example, in "project management", a "calendar" (for marking tasks delivery dates).
- **Generic**: Functionality that maybe needed by any kind of application. For example, authentication and authorization of users.

Subdomains belong to the problem space.

To solve the problem, you model the subdomains, and you create **bounded contexts** (BCs). In practice, a BC is an autonomous application that contains the software model of a subdomain. A BC has its own UL. It is the context on which a term of the UL has a meaning. UL and BCs are the most important things in DDD. UL drives the BCs identification.

Ideally, you should align 1:1 the subdomains of the problem space with the BCs of the solution space, i.e., you should have a BC for each subdomain.

A team can develop one or more BCs, but a BC should be developed by just one team.

BCs belong to the solution space.

**Context Map**: It is a drawing that shows the BCs, and the relationships among them. Every relationship is classified in one of the following patterns:

- Partnership
- Shared Kernel
- Customer-Supplier
- Conformist
- Anticorruption Layer
- Open Host Service
- Published Language
- Separate Ways
- Big Ball of Mud

**Recognizing which pattern to apply in a relationship** it will depend on the particular case you have. Some things that you have to consider are:

- The 2 teams collaborate together.
- One of the teams doesn't care about the other one.
- The teams can negotiate.
- The teams are independent.
- Changes on a model (upstream) affects to the other model (downstream).